A few lines of code get skipped when an irrelevant separate piece of code runs a certain way
Code removed in accordance with the AP guidelines
I am creating a project for the Ap Computer science course, it can be done in any language so I chose Assembly because I have been coding for a long time, and want to get better at Assembly which I had only learned relatively recently.
The idea of the project is that it is a cipher program that is supposed to "Encrypt" an inputted file by changing the ASCII value by using a random list of digits. A piece of the code checks if a character read from the file is ASCII value lower than 32 (space), to skip the piece of code that "encrypts" it. When the inputted file contains a bunch of tabs and newlines, the list only resets once, or twice or not at all, and then it never does again, even if the current character isn't lower than 32.
When I input
btgyuguyg  hgvkuy  k  k    hgc  

it outputs
iyh!yn~~g)#ipwr~}� k  k    hgc   

as you can see it doesn't reset the list and so it stops encrypting.

Single step in a debugger and see what happens.

I've tried, that's how I know that the problem is that the pointer to the current item in the list won't go back to the beginning. But beyond that I don't know what registers or memory addresses to check.

It's a very bad idea to rely on .bss being directly after .data ... you should not use temp to detect the end of Key. Also you are using 64 bit accesses to buffer which is just 8 bits.

Your r.key file seems to only contain 17 digits but you have room for 18. As such the last byte remains a zero. When you process that zero the sub rbx, 48 will turn it into -48 which is then added to the buffer as a 64 bit quantity add [buffer], rbx. Thus, depending on the value of the character buffer can now be a negative 64 bit value. The next time around you read the first byte but then use mov rax, [buffer]; cmp rax, 32; jl which will then think it's less than 32 even though it isn't (compounded by the fact that jl is signed). All of this is easily traceable in a debugger.

@Jester Thanks for your time. I've tried not using temp before and I tried it again and it didn't help. The 17-18 problem there was a reason it was necessary in a previous draft but I fixed it now and it still didn't help. The problem is that r15 is never set back to Key which I know because I was debugging and saw it stay equal to temp.

You can use your debugger to see why it does not go to where you think it should reset.

Thank you for all the help, the following worked:
mov rbx, Key
add rbx, 17
cmp r15, rbx
pushfq      ;# saves the flags
sub rbx, 17
popfq
cmovz r15, rbx

That just seems like a convoluted way of writing cmp r15, Key+17; mov rbx, Key; cmovz r15, rbx

I didn't know you can do that, I've tried cmp r15, Key before and had gotten mismatch opcode and operands error. But I tried what you said and it worked.
